# Issue with deserialize xml using DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have one xml file storing details regarding test

```
<TestUnit>
  <DataDetails>
     <Chart>
      ...............
     </Chart>    
  </DataDetails>
</TestUnit>
```

This xml is configured previously and already deployed.
Now the requirement to add new extended chart node in datadetails which is array of chart elements. We have updated the schema accordingly but facing error while validating previously created XML, because it is not having the new node added in schema.

New XML will look like

```
<TestUnit>
 <DataDetails>
   <Chart>
      ...............
   </Chart>    
   <ExtendedChart>
   </ExtendedChart>
 </DataDetails>
</TestUnit>
```

For newly created XML schema working fine but for previously added XML it is not working.
Throwing exception
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException was caught
  HResult=-2146233076
  Message=Error in line 1 position 38724. 'Element' 'filesField' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestDataObjects' is not expected. Expecting element 'extendedChartField'.

Comment: I'll test when I'm at my desk, but I assume this is to do with the fact that DataContractSerializer expects same-level XML elements to be ordered alphabetically if the order is not explicitly specified in the data contract.

Answer (score 0):

If your XML have different layouts, I recommend you to implement ISerializable interface. By implementing it, you will have to code the serialization and deserialization, but it is not difficult at all. You just have to put conditional serialization on the fields that are not always used.

Feel free to ask help if needed.

Dimitri.

Answer (score 0):

As in my comment, this is because `DataContractSerializer` expects same-level elements to be ordered alphabetically.
Take a look at [this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731138(v=vs.110).aspx) regarding data contract versioning.

As noted , it's possible to set `EmitDefaultValue=false` which will tell `DataContractSerializer` to not output an element if the default value is supplied (usually null or 0) but as mentioned in the article, this is not recommended.

Instead, using the example lifted from the article, you create two distinct classes - one for each version, adding a common value for the `Name` property of the `DataContractAttribute` like so:

```
// Version 1 of a data contract, on machine V1.
[DataContract(Name = "Car")]
public class CarV1
{
    [DataMember]
    private string Model;
}

// Version 2 of the same data contract, on machine V2.
[DataContract(Name = "Car")]
public class CarV2
{
    [DataMember]
    private string Model;

    [DataMember]
    private int HorsePower;
}
```

> The version 2 endpoint can successfully send data to the version 1 endpoint. Serializing version 2 of the Car data contract yields XML similar to the following.

```
<Car>
    <Model>Porsche</Model>
    <HorsePower>300</HorsePower>
</Car>
```

> *The deserialization engine on V1 does not find a matching data member for the HorsePower field, and discards that data.*

And for backward-compatibility:

> The version 1 endpoint can send data to the version 2 endpoint. Serializing version 1 of the Car data contract yields XML similar to the following.

```
<Car>
    <Model>Porsche</Model>
</Car>
```

> The version 2 deserializer does not know what to set the HorsePower field to, because there is no matching data in the incoming XML. *Instead, the field is set to the default value of 0.*

In this example, we are using two different classes so they can both be referred to in the same scope. In practice, these could be the same class, but differing slightly across versions.